# How to determine the pip value for Nikkei 225 in MT4 and CFD's in general?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

I'm trying to determine the pip value for CFD's in *Metatrader4* (MQL4 language). Finding the pip values for Forex pairs is simple, but apparently for CFD's (indices, metals etc.) it's not very clear what to use, as what's referred to as *contracts*, *ticks* and *points* quite disconnected. In addition it depend on the currency used to price the index. (I.e. DEX is EUR, and Nikkei is JPY.) So there is an additional conversion which simply look ugly, and unwieldy.

In particular for the Nikkei 225 CFD (known in MT4 as `JP225` (from ICM) and in TradingView as [NI225](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NI225).)

Assuming 1 Lot, for FX, I use this:

```cpp
...
point = Point;
if((Digits==3) || (Digits==5)) point*=10;

double pipValue = (((MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_TICKVALUE)*point)/MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_TICKSIZE))*LotSize);
Print("INFO: pipValue=" + DoubleToStr(pipValue,Digits));
```

But this gives `0.0000`, which is obviously wrong.

Somewhere buried in the forums, there was the following text:

```
    1 index point  (1.0) = 1 JPY
    For 10 Nikkei contracts, the pip-value = 10 JPY
    The price for 10 contracts = 10*(price level) JPY
    The pipValue in USD = 10 JPY/(USDJPY)
```

**How can this process be automated and calculated for any index or FX pair?**

---

Possibly related, but extremely confusing forum posts and issues:

- https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/271388/page3
- https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/135470
- https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/227407
- https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/271388
- https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/169828
- https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/109552/page4#comment_3049209

Comment: it gives zero because the `LotSize` could be zero, no? `Point` is the tick size (something like 0.00001 if talking about forex), so multiplying tick value by 1.E-5 will give you a very small number. In general, PIP is used in forex jargon meaning around 10$ per movement (when brokers switched to 5-digit quotes, it became 10 minimal 5-digit ticks).

Comment: "Assuming 1 Lot"...  Yes, in fact expanding a few decimals to 5, gave me: `0.00009`, but that doesn't sound right at all. But at this point, I don't even know how to check.

Comment: (1 JPY = 0.0091 USD) as of now.

Comment: Ok, but what is the need in pip value for indices? Use tick values for them instead, and your stop loss / take profit (if fixed size) would be shown in ticks